# Dropdownlist with suggestions that match what you type in a textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown list, a textbox and a button. If I types a word in the textbox and click the button then the dropdown list should select the list item according to that word in the textbox.

For example: If I type 23 then the dropdown should lists the item starting 23.

Comment: Have you tried something, If yes show some code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Generally we expect those who ask questions here to have specific problems with their code -- in other words, you should try something yourself and come to us with just the things about your code that aren't working. For more explanations, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Legends say that StackOverflow is a place where you just describe what you want and the code magically appears in the answer section :O

Comment: I don't have any idea to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GG. is a better option using jQuery UI, but here is a very simple working model not using UI: http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/MA95K/2/

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="Button">
<select>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
</select>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('mousedown', function() {

    var search_str = $('input[type="text"]').val()

    $('option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');

    $('option').each(function() {
        if($(this).text() == search_str)
        {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            return false;
        }
    });
});​
```

---

**Edit**

Here is a new jsfiddle that uses jQuery UI's autocomplete: http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/rPGUy/1/

---

**Edit**

`$('option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');` is basically saying, "find all option tags that have an attribute `selected` with the *value* `selected`, if there are any, and remove that attribute."

So this, for example:

```
<select>
    <option>20</option>
    <option selected="selected">21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
</select>
```

Would become this:

```
<select>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
</select>
```

So now when we have jQuery select a new option tag it won't conflict.

Comment: It works for me, maybe it's not behaving like you expect? I updated my answer to implement the jQuery UI like @GG. suggested.

Comment: Can you please explain the code $('option[selected ="selected"]'.remove Attr[' selected']

Comment: I changed the event to onkeyup   then its working fine for me

Comment: You mean for the [first fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/MA95K/2/)? I set _it_ up to "execute" when you click the button like your question indicated. The [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/rPGUy/1/) is set up with auto-complete so that it executes when you click on one of the auto-complete suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) seems to do exactly what you need, and even better.